# What should be the owner for an external USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, windows-11, usb-storage

I've been using an external drive on 1st PC on a regular basis, I've now switched to a 2nd PC which I use daily.

The drive is a Samsung T7 Shield connected through USB Type C.

When browsing through some of the folders, sometimes UAC pops in and asks that I need to take ownership to be able to browse the directory.

When looking at security properties, I can see that the owner is an unknown SID.

So, what is supposed to be the owner of the drive in first instance?

Answer (score 1):

When you format a drive as NTFS, you allow security settings to be configured on the file and folder structure.

This include access permission (ACL) and ownership.

When you set these permissions, you select a user or group. The user or group is present on your computer, and each user will have a unique System Identification (SID). This SID is only known on your computer and when Windows reads the permission, it will translate the SID and match it with a local user or local group (or domain user/group). If none is found, you see the unknown SID.

Now the problem is that if you change the owner on another computer, it will work fine on that pc, but when you then move the disk to the first computer, that new user or group is not present on this computer and you get the Unknown SID there.

From your question, I was unable to deduce whether or not you still use the first PC or not, so I assumed you still do.

An administrator can always overrule and set the users on an NTFS drive, so its not too big of a problem, but ideally to avoid the problem altogether, you would want to move all the data off of the drive, then reformat the drive as FAT32 or ExFAT, depending on how big it is, and move the data back.

This will remove all security settings as ExFAT does not support security settings.

If you don't use the first PC anymore, you could go to the top level of the drive (Basically This PC, and select the drive letter itself), and right-click and go properties and then to the security tab.

If you now head to advanced and set the owner correctly, you can then at the bottom select to replace ownership on all files and folders on the drive.

After hitting apply, it will scan through all files and folders and set the owner correctly. Note that if you move this drive to a different pc, the same problems will occur again.

Answer (score 1):

The owner doesn't really matter. The owner of a file is only relevant a) for disk space quotas and b) for the ability to *reset* file permissions. Everything else (i.e. normal access) is **not** granted through ownership – it is granted through the Access Control List, i.e. the "Security" tab.

For an external disk, the "Security" tab should just have `Everyone: [x] Full Control` as an access entry, with inheritance enabled for everything underneath. (You can use the "Reapply permissions" checkbox to do a reset at the same time.)

(You might currently have the special `CREATOR OWNER` entry that actually does the job of granting some rights to the owner – feel free to remove it.)

Assigning ownership to the `Administrators` group (which has the same SID everywhere) would make things tidy, but every file or folder that you create *after* doing so will again be owned by yourself and will always appear to be owned by an "unknown SID" on other machines. There's no point in trying to make it consistent, as long as file permissions (the access list) are consistent.